# Scraping with Python to Publish on Wordpress (XML-RPC)

Tags: python, wordpress, xml-rpc

I'm trying to automate a page update on wordpress by scraping a public datasource and doing some cleanup on the HTML/JScript in Python3, then handing it off as a page/post to a wordpress blog.

As always seems to be the case, I'm like 80%-90% there. I have the scraping working properly along with the data cleanup... It's the wordpress side of things were I'm hitting a wall right now. I'm stuck on two issues that both seem like they should be simple, but after looking for a few hours I can't find a ready answer in the wordpress docs about XML-RPC..

The first, seemingly easier issue, is that I really just want to push udpates to a single static page. I'm trying to update a page with some collection stats and charts. By default when I push the new page (or post, doesn't matter) it's creating an entirely new page on wordpress with the same name and the new content, but a different permalink. I'm really hoping this isn't a dead-end, cause it would kill the whole project..

Secondly, the content you pass through XML-RPC to wordpress seems to just be plopped directly into the post. This MOSTLY works for me. However there's a batch of scripting that gets scraped and it seems I need that script to be passed to wordpress as an HTML block. I've tested this by copying and pasting the code manually and can recreate the issue. If I just plop all the HTML and scripts into the page content when editing, most of the content shows up except for the charts generated by the scripts. The scripting and charts don't actually appear on the page at all (there's no garbage output or anything). However If I create an "HTML code" block on the wordpress page and dump all of the scraped data into that block, everything displays perfectly..

So those are the last two sticking points keeping me up tonight. Duplicate pages instead of updated pages, and a couple of beautiful pie charts I can only see if I go through the process manually :(

Any ideas/help is appreciated. I'm happy to share my script kiddy level python code once I anonymize it, but I think both of these are more wordpress/XML-RPC focused issues.

Edit:
Here's the python to wordpress portion of my code, sanitized to remove my personal info:

```
#Configure my wordpress site settings:
your_blog = Client('https://home.XXXXXXXX.com/xmlrpc.php', 'XXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXX')

#Get info on existing posts (debugging):
myposts=your_blog.call(posts.GetPosts())
print(myposts)


#Generate a new page:
page = WordPressPage()
page.title = 'Comic Collection Stats'
page.slug='https://home.XXXXXXXX.com/?p=246'
page.content = str(collection_page)
page.id = your_blog.call(posts.NewPost(page))
page.post_status = 'publish'
your_blog.call(posts.EditPost(page.id, page))
```

Edit2:
After digging further, I'm going to pursue using the Rest API method instead of XML-RPC. XML-RPC appears to be outdated anyways. Hitting snags there as well, but hopefully that's a better timesink since it's a more modern solution.

Comment: Which python wordpress package do you use (such as "python-wordpress-xmlrpc" etc)?

Comment: If possible, also please provide a code snippet that performs the update as basis for further discussions.

Comment: Thanks, I am using python-wordpress-xmlrpc. I also added the relevant portion of my python code, sanitized to remove my info.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, I moved to Rest API instead. The working code to push a page and have the content show up in an HTML block instead of as plain text content is included below (that solves one of the two issues I was having). I'm still stuck getting it to update a static page instead of creating a new one on every upload, but this question was opened for XML-RPC and since I'm already farther with Rest I'm considering this closed.

In the example below, "collection_page" is a Beautifulsoup of the scraped data from the source website. It's converted to a string and encapsulated in wordpress HTML brackets when uploading.

```
#Rest API Version - Set Site and Auth Details:
url = "https://XXXXXXXXX.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/"
user = "XXXXXXXX"
password = "XXXXXXXXX"
credentials = user + ':' + password
token = base64.b64encode(credentials.encode())
header = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token.decode('utf-8')}

#Generate Post:
post = {
        'title' : 'Comics Collection',
        'content': '<!-- wp:html -->' + str(collection_page) + '<!-- /wp:html -->',
        'status': 'publish'
}

#Send the new post:
print(blue + "Pushing up the new post:" + green) ##Debugging Message
response = requests.post(url, headers=header, json=post)
print(blue + "Post Sent" + green) ##Debugging Message

#Show response:
print(url)
print(response)
```